# Enable IPv6 on OVH VPS running Arch

Tags: vps, ipv6, arch-linux, ovh

Having inaugurated my new OVH’s VPS SSD 1 I am greeted by a notification reading

> Your instance is now linked to a free IPv6 in addition to the default IPv4.

Indeed I can see a “IPv6” and a “Gateway” fields.

Problem is: I can’t ping it using this IPv6. I read OVH documentation on the subject but didn’t see anything related to systemd-networkd; and I’m pretty sure it’s what’s being used.

I tried to edit the default /etc/systemd/network/eth0-dhcp.network like this:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

Address=2001:41d0:404:200::21e8/128
Gateway=2001:41d0:404:200::1

[DHCP]
UseMTU=true
```

Now `ip -6 addr show` shows me

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:41d0:404:200::21e8/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe97:9a63/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip -6 route` shows

```
2001:41d0:404:200::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default dev lo proto static metric 1024 pref medium
default via 2001:41d0:404:200::1 dev eth0 proto static metric 1024 pref medium
```

I can ping the gateway’s IP but pinging ipv6.google.com returns

```
Destination unreachable: No route
```

How can I configure my VPS to make it accessible using IPv6?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only obvious problem I see with your network config is:

```
DHCP=yes
```

This should instead be:

```
DHCP=ipv4
```

You are obtaining an IPv4 address with DHCP but configuring IPv6 manually. Thus you only want to [enable DHCP on IPv4](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#DHCP=).

Comment: That makes sense; I updated the configuration but it still doesn’t work. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @MatTheCat Well, obviously `/128` is wrong also, but fortunately it seems to have ignored you there. The live state of the system looks correct. Or maybe it didn't ignore you? I can't ping that address either, but that doesn't necessarily mean anything. Did you try making an outgoing connection? Can you ping the gateway?

Comment: Er I just copied 128 from OVH docs but I don't know what's that means ^^' I can ping the gateway but nothing else as it seems.

Comment: @MatTheCat That should be `/64`, not `/128`. IPv6 subnets are always `/64` except in some very unusual circumstances. I don't know why you would find something else in OVH's docs, but you should fix that.

Comment: Okay so I remplaced `/128` by `/64`. Running `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` does not seem to bring any change.

Comment: @MatTheCat Reboot the VPS before going further.

Comment: Okay now I can ping its IPv4 and IPv6 address! But I no longer can connect through SSH?!

Comment: Uh I guess SSH took its time... Everything is working now thanks a lot!